# Remove the preceeding duplicate index value and keep the first

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, null, break

```
index = [461 470 479 488 489 490 491 492 520 521 522 531 540]

difference = [9 9 9 1 1 1 1 28 9 9]
```

(got this from sub sec index from first index and so on)
code used:

```
    Output = []
     
    for i in range(len(li1)):
        if li1[i] < li2[i]:
            Output.append(li2[i] - li1[i])
            
        else:
            Output.append(li1[i])
             
    print("Original list are :")
    print(li1)
    print(li2)
     
    print("\nOutput list is")`
```

firstly the difference list should look like `[461 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 28 1 1 9 9 540]` which i am unable to do
`[9 9 9 1 1 1 1 28 1 1 9 9 ]`
Above is difference of index value i received, i need to right a code for the above, which read index value
if the difference is 9 read the index value as it is, if its 1, then read the first instance of 1(iterates 5 times) and skip the later instance of 1 then read next value 28, next value is 1, so it read 1(iterates 5 times) and skip next value of 1.

if the value is 1 moves in if loop and it should iterate 5 times and break, i.e skip next values of 1 , i am using break value in while, but it breaks entire loop, where as it should read value with differnce 28, next iteration if its 1 then again enters if and iterates 5 times, and skip next 1's and move to value 9 .

```
for i, j in zip(range(1,len(Output)), s):
    if(Output[i]==1):
        a=0
        while True:
            a=a+1
            if(a==5):
                break
        break
    else:
        print('none')
```

Comment: You should use the keyword `continue` to move on to the next loop iteration.

Comment: Continue would still read next iteration for 1, it doesn't skip,

Comment: The loop value should return as per difference,[461 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 28 1 1 9 9 540], so loop should read [ 416 9 9 9 1(iterates 5 time in while) 28 1(iterates 5 times in while) 9 9 540] the values with greater than 1, will read correctly as the string exist in single lines,

Answer (score 0):

Not certain that I understand the requirement here. Maybe this:

```
index = [461, 470, 479, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 520, 521, 522, 531, 540]

difference = [index[0]] + [b - a for a, b in zip(index, index[1:])] + [index[-1]]

print(difference)
```

**Output:**

```
[461, 9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 28, 1, 1, 9, 9, 540]
```

Comment: Sure will try this, also those are the index values, when serached string from xcel file, so the one with difference 1, are string present one after the other ,if the string is found on index 488, it should read next 5 lines, and move to next iteration value with larger index difference

Comment: It worked, can you advise on adding in loop? i can skip one iteration for value one, but for next one it still reads, and the 1 values may b dyanamic, so cant hard code the iterations to be skipped